# Vector subtraction and scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have been requested to solve this problem:

*For vectors $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n} $ pointing in different directions from the origin, represent geometrically $5\overrightarrow{v}-3\overrightarrow{w}$.*

What I have made is this:

[image: 5v-3w]

Is that geometric representation correct?

Comment: I have edited: $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: This is correct for $R^2$. $R^n$ can't be depicted graphically because nobody has figured out how to depict n dimensions on 2 dimensional paper :)

Comment: @rocinante false. In this case, things are going on in the linear envelope of v and w, which is R^2 subspace of the R^n. So... you can always draw things in that plane, no matter how many irrelevant extra dimensions there are. The picture is fine.

Comment: Not quite correct, both $5v$ and $-3w$ are too short. $v$ is show with a length $2$ diagonals, but $5v$ has only 7 diagonals. $w$ has a length of $1$ width, but $-3w$ has a length of only $8$ widths. Other than that, it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Not quite correct, both $5v$ and $−3w$ are too short. $v$ is shown with a length $2$ diagonals, but $5v$ has only $7$ diagonals. $w$ has a length of $4$ width, but $−3w$ has a length of only $8$ widths. Other than that, it is fine. – [Paul Sinclair](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620160/vector-subtraction-and-scalar-multiplication#comment3302996_1620160)